# How to update a page's content without anyone viewing it (PHP)?

Tags: php

I want to make a PHP page that generates a random number every 10 seconds. In my understanding, someone has to be viewing the page in order for the code to execute (please correct me if I'm wrong). I want to know what code I need to write in order for a random number to generate even when nobody is looking at the page (every 10 seconds and same for all viewers).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a database to store the number and a cronjob to automatically run your script

Comment: As @Rasclatt said, cron job is your best bet, but you could also run the script via PHP CLI.

Comment: If nobody is looking at it, why bother to generate it?

Comment: I'm using an external source to view it. It's sort of like an API. I want it to keep changing even when nobody is accessing it, and I want it to be the same so everything accessing it can be accessing the same value.

Comment: A cron job would actually  be perfect. I realized I only need to regenerate the value every minute, which is the minimum for cron job. Thank you @Rasclatt

Comment: If PHP generates a random number on the server and there's nobody there to read it, is it still generated? Oooooommmmmmm....